# Using larger values than size_t can represent with fwrite

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I know that `fwrite` takes the following parameters:

```
fwrite ( const void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );
```

As far as I know, `size_t` is a typedef and nothing else than:

```
typedef unsigned long size_t;
```

Is it possible to use values greater than `size_t` for count and write?
And if it is not could I connect the written blocks somehow?

Comment: Perhaps call `fwrite()` multiple times?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon. Although you've shown a common definition for `size_t`, it is an implementation-defined type that need not be the same as `unsigned long`.  Successive writes will be 'connected' anyway unless you do something seriously weird.

Comment: well I am calling it multiple times and that is working so far but I would like to increase the size of the single blocks I am writing.. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an application programmers point of view a file is a contiguous series of bytes.  Successive writes will position the data sequentially onto a file.  (This comment is necessary because some will argue details NOT relevant to your question).

Thus:

```
fwrite(&user_record1, sizeof(user_record1), 1, fp);
fwrite(&user_record2, sizeof(user_record2), 1, fp);
```

Results in two user records, one immediately following the other, on the file.

If you have a very large record, then divide it into two smaller records, as:

```
fwrite(&user_record_parta, sizeof(user_record1), 1, fp);
fwrite(&user_record_partb, sizeof(user_record2), 1, fp);
```

However, I would question an application design that uses such large records.  Perhaps what you are really doing in the application is writing an array of user records and that array grows really large.  If this is the case, write each entry of the array, rather than the whole array.

Comment: So writing a really big array of `char`s to a file is quicker when writing each `char` separately?

Comment: @Wolfer, the overhead of calling a write routine for each of 100 chars is greater than the overhead of calling a write for one array of 100 chars.  However, both result in the filling of a buffer that is **NOT** physically written to the file until it is full or a `fflush` is issued.

Answer (score 2):

No, `fwrite` accepts only values that fit in the `size_t` type.

There may be implementation-specific ways to write more but, for standard C, the approach is generally just to do sequential `fwrite` calls. Each subsequent call will append to what you've already written.

And keep in mind that `size_t` is a distinct type. It may be defined as an `unsigned long` is some implementations but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Okay but is it possible to increase the single block in each subsequent so that the block is greater than size_t would allow? Or could i combine blocks later in the file?

Comment: @user2430568, if a 'block' is larger than `size_t` (and this seems _very_ unlikely since it's meant to be the max size of any object the implementation can handle, including arrays), you would have to use separate fread/fwrite calls to handle them. There's no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `fwrite`, the entire object you're writing must be in the object pointed to by `ptr`. Unless you have a really messed-up C implementation, it's impossible to have an object larger than the maximum value of `size_t`, so trying to write more bytes than that would be a programming error, since the pointed-to object is not actually that large anyway.

Comment: Clarification: The reason for this is that `size_t` is supposed to be able to hold the size of any memory structure. In most implementations this means that `size_t` has the same size as a pointer (and thus the same size as the memory address space).

Comment: Well `size_t` is the type of the result of `sizeof` and the type of the argument to `malloc`. I'm not clear on whether it's *conforming* for an implementation to allow larger objects (in other words, to define `size_t` with a type that's too small to represent the sizes of all objects it allows) but it would be a very poor *quality of implementation* to do so. In any case, you can never have objects larger than `(UCHAR_MAX+1)^sizeof(void *)`, just by a simple counting argument (each byte of an object's representation has a unique address).

Answer (score 0):

If you use greater values than `ULONG_MAX` it will just wrap around to 0.

What you can do is write `ULONG_MAX` Bytes, seek to the end position and continue writing, then do that over in a loop, until you've written all your data.

Comment: fwrite writes a certain amount of blocks (count) which have a certain size (size) and i would like to increase the size of the single blocks so the blocks are greater than size_t allows. I think your solution refers to the amount of blocks - or am I misunderstanding something? Thank you!

Comment: @user2430568 Yes mine is referring to the amount of blocks, you can of course write blocks of (max_size_t) size. And write (max_size_t) times. Although another poster brings up a good point regarding the pointers...